Basic Hutchinson-Skilling estimator in Jax
I'm trying to implement the Hutchinson-Skilling estimator (later used in the context of diffusion models) in Jax, but I'm having difficuly understanding why even in some very basic cases, I need so many gaussian samples to have an accurate estimator.
I tried testing it on this super simple example with a function of 2 arguments only, the square of each argument. However, the error is quite random and I need around 10k noise samples to get it down to less than 1% in most cases (depends on the rng key). What's wrong ?
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import random

# Define the function f(x) = x**2
def f(x):
    return x**2

# Define the Hutchinson-Skilling estimator for divergence using Gaussian vectors
def get_div_fn(f,step_rng,num_samples=1000):
    key = step_rng
    
    def hutchinson_skilling_divergence(x):
        def single_sample_divergence(x, key):
            
            v = jax.random.normal(key, shape=x.shape)
            jacobian_vector_product = jax.jvp(f, (x,), (v,))[1]
            return jnp.dot(v, jacobian_vector_product)
        
        keys = jax.random.split(key, num_samples)
        divergence_estimates = jax.vmap(single_sample_divergence, in_axes=(None, 0))(x, keys)

        return jnp.mean(divergence_estimates)
    return hutchinson_skilling_divergence


input = jnp.array([1.0, 1.0])
# Random key for JAX
key = random.PRNGKey(42)
f_div = get_div_fn(f,key)


result = f_div(input)
print(result)


Two comments: I believe that Hutchinson estimation usually is applied to the Hessian (which in general is positive semi-definite) rather than the Jacobian (which in general isn't). I've also generally seen this estimator computed with rademacher-distributed variables rather than normally-distributed variables. Are you sure of the method you're using?

It appears you are doing trace estimation via normally-distributed variables. The expected standard deviation with N trials is σ = sqrt(2 / N) * norm(A). For your case, this gives:
N = 1000
A = jax.jacobian(f)(input)
print(jnp.sqrt(2 / N) * jnp.linalg.norm(A))
# 0.12649111

So it seems like you're getting the expected uncertainty for the function you're using.
You can improve this by using rademacher variates instead of normal variates; then the standard deviation is σ = sqrt{(2 / N) * (norm(A)^2 - norm(diag(A))^2)}, which is always smaller than that of normal variates. For your particular example, the rademacher variates should give you this error:
N = 1000
A = jax.jacobian(f)(input)
print(jnp.sqrt(2 / N * (jnp.linalg.norm(A) ** 2 - jnp.linalg.norm(jnp.diag(A)) ** 2)))
# 0.0

The value is exactly zero, meaning you should converge exactly to the correct result (the exact result comes because your Jacobian is diagonal). You can use the rademacher approach by generating your random variates this way:
v = jax.random.rademacher(key, shape=x.shape).astype(x.dtype)

With this change, your code returns the exact expected value of 4.0 no matter how many samples are used. For general functions with non-diagonal jacobians it won't be exact, but on average it should be more accurate than using normal samples, and in both cases the accuracy will converge at a rate proportional to 1/sqrt(N).

Thanks a lot ! I didn't think about using rademacher variables because the code I was inspiring myself from used exclusively gaussians...(https://github.com/franciscovargas/denoising_diffusion_samplers/blob/main/dds/hutchinsons.py). Another paper of interest to me (http://arxiv.org/abs/2309.17082) mentioned that they got a convergent estimator using normal random variables and a sample size of 10...

Edit : what I'm thinking of for these diffusion model application is that maybe since you use the estimator multiple times if you have a large number of timesteps it keeps the error on the final likelihood quite low since the estimator is unbiased.... I'm going to look into the mathematical details of this statement but what do you think of that ?

Regarding the sample size of 10 - I could believe that if their Jacobian has a norm that's much smaller than the trace. I don't think that will be the case for simple diagonal Jacobians like the one in your experiment.
